# How can I show all the localStorage saved variables?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to acess all the localStorage variables saved on a specific page. How do I do that? I want to show it like I would show an array with the join() function

Comment: *See also*:  [Get HTML5 localStorage keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8419354/1366033)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You could try iterating through all of the items in the localStorage object:

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    // do something with localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
}
```

Comment: I feel it should be mentioned that you can get the key name for _i_ with `localStorage.key(i)`

Comment: Maybe for someone it will be useful- Take note that inside it you cannot `removeItem` from storage because then `localStorage.length` will decrease so `for` will escape sooner than you want. If you want remove items from localStorage then remember to cache length before `for` loop and loop from the end.

Comment: For better performance, the loop should be: `for (var i = 0, l = localStorage.length; i<l; ...`

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev it doesn't make a difference, most browsers cache `localStorage.length` so they don't have to compute it every time

Comment: @user3576887 Any info link how such caching is working?

Comment: Sure, see [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752906) and [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/array-length-in-loop). This applies to arrays, strings, localstorage etc...

Answer (score 37):

I use this block of code frequently:

```
var i;

console.log("local storage");
for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++)   {
    console.log(localStorage.key(i) + "=[" + localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)) + "]");
}

console.log("session storage");
for (i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++) {
    console.log(sessionStorage.key(i) + "=[" + sessionStorage.getItem(sessionStorage.key(i)) + "]");
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Console log the localStorage. It's very simple.

```
console.log(localStorage);
```

Answer (score 15):

you can also check localStorage status and data right in the Google chrome Developer tools:

[image: Localstorage in Chrome Dev Tools]

Answer (score 6):

```
for(var i in localStorage) {
    console.log(i + ' = ' + localStorage[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Taking hints from this page, I'm now using this:

```
new Array(localStorage.length)
  .fill()
  .map(i => localStorage.key(i));
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the situation, the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) functions can be helpful. With their help, it is easy to create an array of keys stored in the `localStorage` or an array of [key, value] pairs. You can then filter such arrays, map them, iterate over them with ease.

---

**Example 1**: displays the keys of all values stored in `localStorage`

```js
console.log(Object.keys(localStorage));
```

**Example 2**: clears `localStorage` except for selected keys

```js
const importantKeys = [ 'JSESSIONID', 'cart' ];
Object.keys(localStorage)
    .filter(key => !importantKeys.includes(key))
    .forEach(key => localStorage.removeItem(key));
```

**Example 3**: iterates over `localStorage` key, value pairs

```js
Object.entries(localStorage).forEach(([ key, value ]) => {
    console.log(`${key} => ${value}`);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend this, the following retrieves everything in the localStorage.

Regardless the type of the entry, ***object, array***,or just a ***value***.

And write all well back in place.

Useful to **save/export/restore** any given config!

```
function getLocalItems(k){
  if (k){
    try{
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(k))
     } catch(e){
       return localStorage.getItem(k)
    }
  }
}

function setLocalItems(k, value){
  if (typeof value === 'object') {
    value = JSON.stringify(value)
  }
  localStorage.setItem(k, value)
}

// Put all entries in an object «store»
let store = {}
for (let i = 0, l = localStorage.length; i < l; i++) {
  store[localStorage.key(i)] = getLocalItems(localStorage.key(i))
}
console.log(store)

// Write all keys of «store» in localStorage
for (let o in store) {
  setLocalItems(o, store[o])
}
```

You can then send this «store» object to your server, for backup/restore after login.

After experiments, in the case of heavy usage of the localStorage, it is a good idea to use this «store» object in scripts, this keeps all values in memory for faster i/o access, because no hard write on disk.

Either way the localStorage is extremely powerful, we can make complex stuffs. Use it in a way that your scripts won't fail if the localStorage keys are missing or corrupted.

Allowing users to erase all local configs with a button or automatic after logout, is also a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

I refined the [script by Cryptopat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54471570/1824988) to be copy+paste ready, and work with both localStorage as well as sessionStorage. This is handy to reproduce the full storage 1:1 on a different machine.

Tested on Chrome 74.0.3729.131.

```
function dump(storage) {
    let store = []
    for (let i = 0, l = storage.length; i < l; i++) {
        let key = storage.key(i);
        store.push({ key: key, value: storage.getItem(key) });
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(store))
}

function restore(storage, store, clearBefore) {
    if (clearBefore) {
        storage.clear();
    }

    for (let i = 0, l = store.length; i < l; i++) {
        let item = store[i];
        storage.setItem(item.key, item.value);
    }
}

// usage:
// 
// dump(localStorage); // manual step: copy log output to text file
// dump(sessionStorage);
//
// let contentsFromTextFile = [ ... ]; // manual step: paste from text file
// restore(localStorage, contentsFromTextFile, true);
// restore(sessionStorage, contentsFromTextFile, true);
//
//
// EXAMPLE
// -------
// Given localStorage has one entry with key "foo" and value "bar"
// And I pasted the above code into the console
//
// When I run
//    dump(localStorage)
// Then I see the log output
//    [{"key":"foo","value":"bar"}]
//
// When I run
//    restore(localStorage, [{"key":"foo2","value":"bar2"}], true);
// Then localStorage contains only one entry with key "foo2" and value "bar2"
//
// When I run
//    restore(localStorage, [{"key":"foo3","value":"bar3"}], false);
// Then localStorage contains two entries,
//   one entry with key "foo2" and value "bar2" and
//   one entry with key "foo3" and value "bar3"
```