# Is reading the `length` property of an array really that expensive an operation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, micro-optimization

I always assumed caching the length of an array in JavaScript is a good idea (especially in the condition of a `for` loop) because of the expensiveness of calculating the length of an array.

#### Example

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { }

// vs

for (var i = 0, arrLength = arr.length; i < arrLength; i++) { }
```

However, I thought perhaps the `length` property is only updated on creation and alteration of the array. Therefore, reading it shouldn't be too expensive an operation as opposed to reading it stored in a variable (as opposed to other methods in other languages that may need to seek in memory to find the end of something, e.g. `strlen()` in C).

I have two questions. I am also interested in how this works, so please don't hit me with the *premature optimisation* stick.

Assume the JavaScript engines in browsers.

1. Is there any advantage to caching the `length` property of an array in JavaScript? Is there much more involved in reading a local variable over an object's property?
2. Is the `length` property simply altered on creation and on `shift()` and `pop()` type methods that don't return a new array and otherwise simply stored as an integer?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Well, I would have said it was expensive, but then I wrote a little test @ [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/array-length-in-loop) and to my surprise using `i<array.length` actually was faster in Chrome, and in FF(4) it didn't matter.

My suspicion is that length is stored as an integer (Uint32). From the ECMA-specs (262 ed. 5, page 121):

> Every Array object has a 
>   length property whose value is always a nonnegative integer less than  2<sup>32</sup>. The value of the  length property is
>   numerically greater than the name of
>   every property whose name is an array
>   index; whenever a property of an Array
>   object is created or changed, other
>   properties are adjusted as necessary
>   to maintain this invariant.
>   Specifically, whenever a property is
>   added whose name is an array index,
>   the length property is  changed, if
>   necessary, to be one more than the
>   numeric value of that array index; and
>   whenever the length property is
>   changed, every property whose name is
>   an array index whose value is not
>   smaller than the new length is
>   automatically deleted. This constraint
>   applies only to own properties of an
>   Array object and is unaffected by
>   length or array index properties that
>   may be inherited from its prototypes

Phew! I don't know if I ever get used to such language ...

Finally, we always have our good old lagging behind browser. In IE (9, 8, 7) caching the length is really faster. One of many more reasons to not use IE, I say.

Comment: In my Chrome 10.0.648.127 on Linux i686 it didn't matter as well.

Comment: Arrays in scripting languages (Ruby, Perl, ...) usually know two lengths as simple integers: how many slots have been allocated and how many slots are in use (i.e. the length). Anyone that would do it differently in a JavaScript engine probably shouldn't be allowed anywhere near a compiler :) Arrays usually know how long they are without computing it. Except in C of course.

Comment: Since most modern JS engines actually do some JIT compiling, I expect them to simply identify such a common idiom and replace it with the most efficient variant. So the Java rule becomes true again: write simple, straightforward code.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer. Suppose that's true. Anyway, why should *write simple, straightforward code* be claimed as a Java rule?

Comment: It's not **just** a Java rule, but in Java it's sometimes quoted for *performance reasons*. There's a often-quoted article titled ["Write Dumb Code"](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Interviews/devinsight_1/#1).

Comment: I'd say that since caching the length does make a difference in IE and IE (at least  before IE 9) is the hugely slowest browser, it's an optimization that could be worthwhile.

Comment: @Tim Down: it makes a difference in IE9 too! The script engine in that browser still seems to lag behind a few era.

Comment: For LG and Samsung Smart TVs and PS4 (they're WebKit based), you have pretty much a very similar behaviour than a Safari browser. So this caching makes a lot of difference.

Answer (score 30):

TL;DR:

From what I can gather, it *seems* like the length of the array is cached internally (at least in V8)..

(Details? Read on :))

So, this question has dinged around in my head a few times and I've decided to get to the root of the problem (at least, in one implementation).

Digging around V8 source yielded the [JSArray](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#W9JxUuHYyMg/trunk/src/objects.h&q=jsarray%20package%3ahttp://v8%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=6057) class.

```
// The JSArray describes JavaScript Arrays
//  Such an array can be in one of two modes:
//    - fast, backing storage is a FixedArray and length <= elements.length();
//       Please note: push and pop can be used to grow and shrink the array.
//    - slow, backing storage is a HashTable with numbers as keys.
```

I'm making an assumption that the type of array elements dictates whether it's fast or slow. I got down to a bit flag being set in `set_has_fast_elements` (`set_bit_field2(bit_field2() | (1 << kHasFastElements))`), which is where I figured I'd draw the digging line as I was looking in google code and don't have the source locally.

Now, it *seems* that **any** time **any** operation is done on the array (which is a child class of `JSObject`, a call is made to `NormalizeElements()`, which executes the following:

```
// Compute the effective length.
  int length = IsJSArray() ?
      Smi::cast(JSArray::cast(this)->length())->value() :
      array->length();
```

So, in answering your questions:

1. There doesn't seem to be any advantage in Chrome (or other browsers that use V8) to caching the `length` property of an array (unless you're doing something odd that would force it to be `slow` (I'm not sure what those conditions are) - having said that, I'll most likely continue to cache `length` until I get a chance to go through *all* OS browser implementations ;)
2. The `length` property seems to be altered after *any* operation on the object.

**Edit:**

On a side note, it seems that an "empty" array is actually allocated to have 4 elements:

```
// Number of element slots to pre-allocate for an empty array.
static const int kPreallocatedArrayElements = 4;
```

I'm not sure how many elements the array grows by once the bounds have been exceeded - I didn't dig *that* deep :)

Comment: Typical implementations will grow the array by a constant multiple of the size of the array - usually by doubling, by tripling, quadrupling, etc. all yield the same amortized `O(1)` for inserting.

Comment: @matt: thanks - would have figured as much, but didn't *know* for sure as I didn't dig deeper :)

Comment: That's one long tl;dr, but +1 for digging browser source code.

Answer (score 14):

Another set of performance [tests](http://jsperf.com/cached-array-length). The loop is done over an array of million random numbers with an empty loop.

In Chrome, the loops with cached and non-cached lengths clock pretty much the same times, so I am guessing it's a [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) optimization to cache the length.

In Safari and Firefox, the cached length was consistently about 2x faster than the non-cached version.

Comment: In Firefox 40 the cached and non-cached version have the same performance.

Comment: How about Firefox now? In 2023, version 102?

Answer (score 8):

This article investigates automatic caching in V8 and Chrome, by asking [IRHydra](http://mrale.ph/irhydra/2/) for the generated code:

> [How the Grinch stole array.length access](http://mrale.ph/blog/2014/12/24/array-length-caching.html) by Vyacheslav Egorov

He found that *under certain conditions* manually caching the `.length` actually added overhead rather than improving performance!

But anyway, this kind of micro-optimization is unlikely to achieve any noticeable gain for your users.  For their benefit, and for yours, focus instead on code that is clear to read, and using good data structures and algorithms in your code!

[Avoid premature optimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize): Focus on elegant code until a performance issue arises.  Only then, seek out the bottleneck through profiling, and then optimise *just that part* of the code.

Answer (score 4):

Just a note:

On some browsers (I've noticed it in Safari, IE, and Opera), you can get a speed boost by caching the length inside the for loop declaration:

```
var j;
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
  j = arr[i];
}
```

I edited @KooiInc's jsperf test above to [add this case](http://jsperf.com/array-length-in-loop/10).

Comment: Of interest, I just ran this test on the main four browsers (now included in the chart) and storing length is a pretty noticeable positive in IE and Safari, but it provides no benefit in Chrome and Firefox. Surprisingly, Firefox blew the other browsers away. Unsurprisingly, Safari was by far the slowest in my test.

Answer (score 3):

Take care not to assume that this is true for all iterable collections. For example caching the length of an HTMLCollection is 65% faster in Chrome (Version 41) and 35% faster in Firefox (Version 36).

http://jsperf.com/array-length-in-loop-dom

Comment: Also important to note that the `length` isn't static in a HTMLCollection, it will adjust to reflect elements matched.