# How to loop over an Array with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a string that has data separated by a pipe character (`|`).

#### Example

```
var somestring = "data1|data2|data3";
var separated = somestring.split("|");
```

I know how to use the `split()` to separate each data.

However, I don't know how many pipes there will be in the resulting `Array`.

In jQuery or JavaScript, how do I loop over the array returned?

Comment: asked 5 mins ago, already 7 answers, I love stack overflow sometimes...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> In jQuery or JavaScript, how do I loop through each separated variable?

You basically just need to iterate over the resulting `Array`.

### jQuery

#### [`$.each` loop](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

This method is easy to work with, and benefits in the variables used being encapsulated.

```
$.each(separated, function(index, chunk) {
    // `chunk` is each member of the array.
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Hhvmn/).

Of course, jQuery *is* JavaScript so any of the below methods will also work.

### JavaScript

#### [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

This is the recommended way.

```
for (var i = 0, length = separated.length; i < length; i++) {
    var chunk = separated[i];
    // `chunk` is each member of the array.
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/CWMTf/).

You'll notice too the `length` property is cached so it is not looked up on each iteration. [Some browsers already optimise for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752906/is-reading-the-length-property-of-an-array-really-that-expensive-an-operation-i/5752991#comment-6587899), however IE appears to still benefit from it cached. It only takes 5 seconds to do, so you may as well keep IE users happy too.

You may want to define `i` and `chunk` outside of the `for` loop, because JavaScript has no block scope (unless you're using `let`), and those variables will exist before (declaration hoisted) and after (no block scope).

#### [`for ( in )` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

This loop is generally not recommended, as it should be used for iterating over object properties only, not array like member properties.

```
for (var chunk in separated) {
     if ( ! separated.hasOwnProperty(chunk)) {
         continue;
     }
     // `separated[chunk]` is each member of the array.   
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/HECjq/).

This loop will loop over all properties up the prototype chain, so `hasOwnProperty()` must be used. For this reason it is not recommended for arrays.

#### [`for ( of )` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

This loop is standardized in ECMA 6 and is able to loop over `NodeList`s and iterators.

```
for (var chunk of separated) {
     // `chunk` is each member of the array.   
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flyingsheep/kPkXy/)

#### [`forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach)

This method is an addition to the ECMA-262 standard. It's not available in IE8, but it can be [shimmed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility) relatively easily.

```
separated.forEach(function(chunk, index) {
     // `chunk` is each member of the array.   
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Fq9Rg/).

### Other specialised methods

If you're looking to iterate for a specific goal, it may be useful to use a specialised iterator. Keep in mind these also don't have the best browser support.

#### [`filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Creates a mew array of the elements which the associated callback returned *truthy* for.

```
separated.filter(function(element) {
    return +element > 255;
});
```

#### [`reduce` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Creates a new value based on reducing the elements of the array, from left to right.

```
separated.reduce(function(accumulator, element) {
    return accumulator.concat(element);
}, "");
```

See also the [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) method.

#### [`map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Creates a new array, replacing each element with the returned value of the associated callback.

```
separated.map(function(element) {
    return element.substr(0, 1);
});
```

#### [`every` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Returns a boolean value of which is the result of every element in the array passing the test. This method short circuits, i.e. it returns whenever one element's callback doesn't return *truthy*.

```
separated.every(function(element) {
    return element.substr(0, 1) == "a";
});
```

#### [`some` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Returns a boolean value of which is the result of some element in the array passing the test. This method short circuits, i.e. it returns whenever one element's callback passes the test.

```
separated.some(function(element) {
    return element.substr(0, 1) == "a";
});
```

Comment: +1 for an education on javascript `for` loops, I learnt two new things today and it's not even lunch time

Comment: Yeah alex! Perfect answer! +1

Answer (score 1):

`separated.length` should be all you need.

Answer (score 1):

str.split() returns an array of values, so in your example, since 'separated' is an array,  you could:

```
for (var i=0, len=separated.length; i < len; i++) {
   // do something with separated[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in jquery like this

```
$.each(separated,function(key,item){ alert('here is ' + item + ' at position ' + key) })
```

Answer (score -1):

If your question really is "how do I loop through each separated variable?" then:

```
for (var i = 0; i < separated.length; i++)
{
 //Do something with separated[i];
}

//or  (apparently this is deprecated)

for(var a in separated)
{
  //Do something with a
}
```

Comment: for(var a in array) is deprecated and *should not* be used.

Comment: Didn't realize that, I was thinking of how I usually do it in C#. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Rob It's not deprecated, it is just not the best loop for iterating over an `Array`.

Comment: @Alex, best practice states for-in is to be used to iterate the properties of an object, not the elements of an array. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference

Comment: @Rob True, but it isn't deprecated anywhere is it?

Comment: You're correct. I should have used a better term than deprecate (to express strong disapproval of) like 'illegal', 'misuse', 'lazy' or 'fraught with danger'. Either way, iterating an array with a language feature specifically designed for another, unrelated purpose is a *really bad* thing to do.

Answer (score -1):

Loop through with a FOR...NEXT construct like in most other languages:

```
var somestring = "data1|data2|data3";
var separated = somestring.split("|");

for (i=0 ; i<separated.length; i++) {
 document.write(separated[i]);
 document.write("<br/>");
}
```