# JavaScript how to for loop different elements as a variable to apply in same functions

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript,this question may looks very silly.

I have function like this:

```
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
        var container = document.getElementById('mySelectOptions');
        if (!container.contains(e.target)) {
            container.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
```

And another almost same function like this:

```
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
        var container = document.getElementById('newSelectOptions');
        if (!container.contains(e.target)) {
            container.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
```

The only difference is the id ,my question is how to add the 2 ids into this same function ?

maybe something like this:

```
for id in ['mySelectOptions','newSelectOptions']:
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    var container = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!container.contains(e.target)) {
        container.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: Why don't you set a class for both elements that share the same event listener?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop over an Array with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208964/how-to-loop-over-an-array-with-javascript)

Comment: @PeterB can you give me example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `.querySelectorAll` to select all match elements with different id. These id can be write with `,` splitter (`#newSelectOptions,#mySelectOptions`).

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    var containers = document.querySelectorAll('#newSelectOptions,#mySelectOptions');
    [...containers].forEach(function(container) {
        if (!container.contains(e.target)) {
            container.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use `containers.forEach...` because querySelector will return a node list.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that wrap your DOM function code

```js
function hideContainer(containerId) {
    var container = document.getElementById(containerId);
    if (!container.contains(e.target)) {
        container.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    hideContainer('mySelectOptions');
});


document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    hideContainer('newSelectOptions');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `array` of the Ids in case you do not want to work with `classes`.

```
let elemntsIds= ['mySelectOptions', 'newSelectOptions'];

elemntsIds.forEach(function(id) {
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    var container = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!container.contains(e.target)) {
      container.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
});
```

Keep in mind that I used the `let` for defining the array outside the **`function handler`** body since it is `block-scoped`, you will need to declare it as var inside the function handler body so it can be `hoisted` and to avoid a new instance from being created each time the **event** is triggered

Comment: declaring it as a `var` does hoist it to the top of the callback, but it still declares a new variable (and runs the query) every time the event is triggered. If you want a closure, declare it as a `const` before the `addEventListener` call.