# Does the .length property gets evaluated on every iteration of a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I've been unable to find the answer to this, say for example you have the array:

```
var myArray = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]; // pretend I define up to 1000 elements
```

One simple approach to iterate through the array would be:

```
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
    console.log(myArray[i]);
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is if  the .length property will be evaluated on each iteration, then if I use:

```
my len = myArray.length;
for(var i=0; i<len i++){
    console.log(myArray[i]);
}
```

Does the 2nd approach will be a performance improvement ? Does the `JS` engine will calculate the `length` on each iteration?

Comment: Found this exact question (or very similar): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821156/set-length-to-variable-or-calculate-length-within-loop-statment

Comment: Depends on the engine. It might be smart enough, but we can't expect it in general. Especially on older engines where it's more relevant…

Comment: It's a property lookup, and will happen on every iteration, but it's not a "calculation" of the `.length`. It's a stored property that is updated when the Array changes in length.

Comment: ...and `int i=0;` isn't valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does! I like this solution

```
for(var i=0, len=myArray.length; i<len; i++){
    console.log(myArray[i]);
}
```

It's just a little cleaner than the one you pasted.

Comment: Never use `for in` with an array! Then `i` also becomes `length`, which is not an element of the array (but it's a property)

Comment: Ok, I removed `for-in` example. Oriol, can you tell me why not?

Comment: Also your first example has a syntax error, you're missing a semicolon somewhere between `i<len` and `i++`

Comment: See here why you shouldn't - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Comment: Also, JavaScript doesn't have `int`, though I'm sure that was not noticed when copied from the question.

Comment: @Oriol: No, because `length` is nonenumerable. But other properties (even on the prototype) might be

Comment: Lol, sorry I copy/pasted and modified his original code. I didn't realize all the syntax errors at first glance.

Comment: The `.length` is non-enumerable on Arrays, but often enumerable on Array-like objects, like some host provided node collections.

Comment: @Bergi Ah, you're right. But some old browsers iterated over 'length', 'toString', etc.

Comment: Another reason not to use `for...in` for arrays: The order in which the elements are iterated over is not guaranteed. And normally use arrays because order matters (I would say).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it will only be a noticeable performance improvement if this loop is executed many millions of times. However, if rather than `.length`, that value was a complex calculation, by all means do that, especially if it will be run millions of times.

For example, if you are looping up to `length` to the, say, 20th power, you should not do that every iteration.