# NodeJS for loop optimization

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, v8

I know that in browser it is more optimal to write a for loop along the lines of

```
 for(var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++){ }
```

instead of

```
 for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){ }
```

But is this true in NodeJS or does the V8 engine optimize it?

I know in [ecma-262 5.1 sec-15.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4) array length is defined as such:

> The value of the length property is numerically greater than the name of every property whose name is an array index; whenever a property of an Array object is created or changed, other properties are adjusted as necessary to maintain this invariant.

Thus if the length doesn't change the only reason this method would be slower is because you have to access the property.  What I'm looking for is a reasonable example/ explanation that would show whether or not the V8 engine (which is used in NodeJS) suffers in performance when accessing this property.

Comment: talk about micro-optimizations...

Comment: i guess there is no optimization, because it's a statement that need to be checked every loop

Comment: @AmitJoki that's true this is a micro-optimization, but I would sleep better at night knowing the answer :)

Comment: @SleepDeprivedBulbasaur yeah, you're already sleep deprived :)

Comment: You could try to test perf and see if there is any difference with those engines

Comment: @jlonganecker I am looking for evidence to support that it is faster in node, just saying "it is faster because I said so" isn't really helping :/.  Thank you though

Comment: `l = arr.length` is better only in IE8. In modern browser it can lead to slightly **decreased** performance - [see this blog entry](http://mrale.ph/blog/2014/12/24/array-length-caching.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752906/is-reading-the-length-property-of-an-array-really-that-expensive-an-operation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `arr` is a pure local variable and the loop doesn't touch it in any way, then yes. However even if the optimization fails, loading the same field over and over again doesn't really cost anything due to CPU cache.

Comment: @Alnitak Doesn't matter how big or small it is, it is stored 12/24 bytes away from the array pointer which fits in all CPU cache lines

Comment: sure, if the JIT is clever enough to perform that optimisation for the array object, and optimise away the property access too.  My argument would be, if you know the loop length doesn't change, then _why not_ write the loop that way and allow even the dumbest JS interpreter to take advantage of the invariant.

Comment: @Alnitak it's not about optimization, V8 represents all arrays this way.

Comment: I suppose my question is specifically about the V8 compiler, do you have any supporting resources? @Esailija

Comment: it's just the first one I found.  Do you have a better performance test framework available? :)

Comment: I had to go Christmas shopping so ill check it later

Comment: I would like to add that if hoisting of `arr.length` fails V8 will still have to reload length e.g. for a bounds check - so eliminating one explicit length load manually doesn't in fact eliminate all accesses to length property, implicit ones will remain. In this case hoisting one access manually can actually lead to a worse code, because you end up with two "unconnected" live values - more live values, higher register pressure and potentially more spill/restore code.

Answer (score 3):

I would always use the first *if applicable* because it informs both the interpreter and *any future reader of the code* that the loop does not modify the length of the array.

Even if it's not faster (although http://jsperf.com/array-length-vs-cached suggests it actually is) it's simply good practise to factor constant expressions from outside of a loop.

Comment: Yes, so chrome performance being boosted would indicate that it would also be faster on the NodeJS V8 engine then?  Since that is my specific use case.

Comment: If Chrome is still using V8 (ISTR it is?) then the results from Chrome _should_ extrapolate to V8.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is length's calculation. In this example `for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){ }` statement `arr.length` will be calculated at every loop iteration. But with `for(var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++){ }` value will be taken without any calculations. Simply getting a value is faster than calculating length of the array.
Getting length can't be optimized by any compiler because it could be changed. So it's calculated each iteration.