# How to get all objects in Darts Storage

Tags: dart, local-storage, dart-html

As mention in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419354/get-html5-localstorage-keys), this is the way t get all objects stored in a localstorage:

```dart
for (var key in localStorage){
   console.log(key)
}
```

How would I do the same in Dart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the keys and values from Dart's [local storage](http://api.dartlang.org/html/Storage.html) in almost the same way

```dart
Element log = document.query('#log');
log.nodes.clear();
for(int i=0; i<window.localStorage.length; i++) {
    var elm = new Element.tag("p");
    var key = window.localStorage.key(i);
    elm.innerHTML = "key ${key} value ${window.localStorage.getItem(key)}"; 
    log.nodes.add(elm);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but what is the `Storage` class for. I thought it was the dart implementation of localStorage.

Comment: Ok, the new [Api docs](http://api.dartlang.org/dom/Storage.html) make it more clear **Storage is not the same as the DOM:Storage**

Comment: @AndreasKöberle interesting I was quite sure that it abstracted DOM:Storage. New docs a way better though.