# IE8 and localStorage support

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am not sure if IE8 fully supports localStorage.
But I use the following method to detect

```
function supports_html5_storage() 
{
    try { 
    return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null; 
    } 
    catch (e) {
    return false; 
    } 
}
```

Now IE returns true for 'localStorage' in window

But returns undefined for window['localStorage']

So should I update this method OR does IE8 indeed have local storage support ?

Comment: IE8 supports `localStorage`. Can I Use is a quick way to verify such: http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to set and read localStorage.

Some browsers return a security error
if cookies are disabled or you are working with file: protocol.

```
function hasStorage(){
    try{
        localStorage.setItem('test', '7');
        if(localStorage.getItem('test')=== '7'){
            localStorage.removeItem('test');
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch(er){}
    return false;
}
```

**alert(hasStorage())**

Answer (score 5):

Here is a famous localStorage plugin  https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/
you can add, edit and delete datas very easily and the most important is you can use localstorage in IE6+.

store.js uses localStorage when available, and falls back on the userData behavior in IE6 and IE7. No flash to slow down your page load. No cookies to fatten your network requests.
Ex :

```
store.set('user', { name: 'marcus', likes: 'javascript' })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/):

```
if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
  // localStorage is available
}
```