# IE extension local storage backup

Tags: c#, html, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to create an IE extension which is capable of reading the iframes and search for the status of another extension.

Say i have an extension myextension1 which saves its data in local storage in IE and when my users clear the cache the data is lost! I want to retain that information using another extension called myextension2 which will constantly check if myextension1's local storage contains data or not, if there is data it checks and updates its own persistent data file or else writes data into the first app's local storage.

Is this possible in IE8? cause it is possible in Mozilla, chrome and safari using JavaScript and it's done successfully.

I am using C# for IE development, any suggestions and ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I dont get the answer from your possible duplicate link! I am trying to access local storage of one extension from another and the link you gave doesnt explain much on how to access

Comment: Try this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313606/ie8-and-localstorage-support