# How to retrieve all localStorage items without knowing the keys in advance?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to show all of the keys and storage written before. 
My code is below. I created a function (allStorage) but it doesn't work. 
How can I do this?

```
    function storeUserScribble(id) {
        var scribble = document.getElementById('scribble').innerHTML;
        localStorage.setItem('userScribble',scribble);
    }

    function getUserScribble() {
        if ( localStorage.getItem('userScribble')) {
            var scribble = localStorage.getItem('userScribble');
        }
        else {
            var scribble = 'You can scribble directly on this sticky... and I will also remember your message the next time you visit my blog!';
        }
        document.getElementById('scribble').innerHTML = scribble;
    }

    function clearLocal() {
        localStorage.clear();
        return false;
    }

    function allStorage() {
        var archive = [];
        for (var i = 0; i<localStorage.length; i++) {
            archive[i] = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: `length` is spelled as `lenght` in your code. FYI.

Comment: *See also*:  [Get HTML5 localStorage keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8419354/1366033)

Comment: `Object.keys(localStorage)`

Answer (score 150, accepted):

If you modify your function to this you can list all items based on key (will list the items only):

```
function allStorage() {

    var values = [],
        keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
        i = keys.length;

    while ( i-- ) {
        values.push( localStorage.getItem(keys[i]) );
    }

    return values;
}
```

[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is a new addition to JavaScript (ECMAScript 5). It lists all own keys on an object which is faster than using a for-in loop which is the option to this.

However, this will not show the keys. For that you need to return an object instead of an array (which is rather point-less IMO as this will bring you just as far as you were before with localStorage just with a different object - but for example's sake):

```
function allStorage() {

    var archive = {}, // Notice change here
        keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
        i = keys.length;

    while ( i-- ) {
        archive[ keys[i] ] = localStorage.getItem( keys[i] );
    }

    return archive;
}
```

If you want a compact format listing then do this instead - here each item in the array will have `key=item` which you later can split into pairs and so forth:

```
function allStorage() {

    var archive = [],
        keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
        i = 0, key;

    for (; key = keys[i]; i++) {
        archive.push( key + '=' + localStorage.getItem(key));
    }

    return archive;
}
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about `Object.keys`, +1

Comment: Exactly what i need, i was trying to make it with array , but it didn't works, when i change it to object works with me, Thanks also for the description :)

Comment: Don't forget about `Object.entries`!

Answer (score 183):

The easiest way in ES2015+ is:

```
const items = { ...localStorage };
```

Comment: What voodo is this? [Spread syntax?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Doesn't this run into the hasOwnProperty problem?

Comment: @Kzqai It returns only enumerable properties, so no additional hasOwnProperty check needed.

Comment: Neat but doesn't answer the question. You just get a new object.

Comment: @aspiring-dev In the question it's not clear enough which type should be returned. Anyway, the object can be easily transformed to necessary from using Object.keys, Object.values or Object.entries function

Comment: @atilkan you are wrong: `localStorage` will return instance of `Storage` object; whereas `{...localStorage}` - a simple object

Comment: @AspiringDev You get a new object, containing all the key values, without having to know them in advance. Isn't that what the question asks?

Comment: `Object.keys(localStorage)`

Answer (score 27):

The easiest way would be to use:

```
return JSON.stringify(localStorage);
```

Answer (score 24):

`localStorage` is not an array, but an object, so try sth. like this:

```
for (var a in localStorage) {
   if (!localStorage.hasOwnProperty(a)) continue;
   console.log(a, ' = ', localStorage[a]);
}
```

Comment: That will also list functions.

Comment: @Nux it doesn't for me

Comment: Strange... Seem to only be a problem in Firefox.

Comment: I guess you need to use localStorage.hasOwnProperty(a) for it not to list functions

Comment: This is what it returns 

clear  =  ƒ clear() { [native code] }
getItem  =  ƒ getItem() { [native code] }
key  =  ƒ key() { [native code] }
removeItem  =  ƒ removeItem() { [native code] }
setItem  =  ƒ setItem() { [native code] }

Comment: @VishalGoyal I updated the answer based on the comment above yours :-)

Comment: @DziadBorowy - Thanks :hands_celebrating

Answer (score 14):

```
// iterate localStorage
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {

  // set iteration key name
  const key = localStorage.key(i);

  // use key name to retrieve the corresponding value
  const value = localStorage.getItem(key);

  // console.log the iteration key and value
  console.log('Key: ' + key + ', Value: ' + value);  

}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(localStorage)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little more succinct:

```
function getAllLocalStorage() {
    return Object.keys(localStorage)
        .reduce((obj, k) => {
            return { ...obj, [k]: localStorage.getItem(k)}}, {});
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**To get all of the "localStorage", copy it and set the `localStorage` where you want**

```
let localstorage= {...localStorage}
let content = 'localStorage.clear()

$.each(localstorage,(i,e)=> {
   content+=`localStorage.setItem('${i}','${e}');`}) 
copy(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop with `hasOwnProperty` to check if object has key.

```
for (var key in localStorage) {
    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key, ' = ', localStorage[key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return all of the set keys

```js
const getLocalStorageObject = () => {
    storage = {}
    let index = 0

    while (localStorage.key(index) !== null) {
        const key = localStorage.key(index);
        storage[key] = localStorage.getItem(key)
        index += 1
    } 

    return storage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you, I added a **rest** parameter, this allows only leaving the properties that are needed

```
  localStorage.setItem("clear", "values")
  const {clear, ...rest } = localStorage;



  function allStorage(val) {
    const { ...rest } = localStorage;
    return val ? Object.keys(rest) : Object.values(rest);
  }
  console.log(allStorage(false));
```

Answer (score -1):

Get an array of localStorage keys this way:

```
console.log('keys: ', localStorage._keys)
```

Should probably be obvious from trying out the 'Correct Answer', but if you want to iterate through or search just the key names, `localStorage._keys` is your simple starting point.

Comment: I don't see this working. Did you tried this on Chrome console? or can you share some document where you find localStorage._keys property?

Comment: Hey @JCrist, welcome to SO! Thank you for the contribution, but your answer does not work. The **localStorage** object does not have a *native property* called **_keys**.

Answer (score -2):

These are all bulky or downright incorrect.

The **Correct Answer** is:
`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage))`