# Check if exist any Key localStorage Javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage, web-storage

I need to check if there is any key in localStorage
This code did not work

```
    if (localStorage.user === undefined) {
      alert('There is no key!'); 
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a Storage item is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262605/how-to-check-whether-a-storage-item-is-set)

Comment: Or also look here and add your own code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745292/all-local-storage-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (Object.keys(localStorage).length === 0) {
  alert('There is no key!'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use getItem

```
if (localStorage.getItem("user") === null) {
    alert('Não há chave!'); 
}
```

**EDIT**
You can check if the localstorage is empty by

```
if (localStorage.length == 0)
```

Comment: I need to check any key, not a specific key.