# reordering the localstorage after deletion of an entry

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Is there a way of changing a key in a localstorage?
For example, if I have a key set to "4" and value of "myvalue" and I'd like to change the key to 3. What would the process be?

Would I have to getItem first and then Setitem with an index-1?

[image: for instance, the user clicks a certain button and creates an indexed localstorage entry like so-]

[image: Then, he has the option to delete an entry which will leave him like so:]

I want to call a function on page unload that reorders the keys and sets 3 to 2 (reindex it).

Ideas would be appreciated

Comment: do you want to exchange them or simple replace 2 and delete 3?

Answer (score 2):

You'll first have to set the new value, before deleting the old one. Like this:

```
function changeKey(oldKey, newKey) {
    localStorage.setItem(newKey, localStorage.getItem(oldKey));
    localStorage.removeItem(oldKey);
}
```

I would suggest that you do not use the localStorage as an array like that though, but instead use a single localStorage item to store your array:

```
var myArray = [ { a : 1 }, { b : 2 } ];

localStorage.setItem("myArray", JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

Then whenever you want to manipulate the array, you can do it like this, and the array indexes will update automatically:

```
var myArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myArray")); // Fetching the array

myArray.splice(myIndex, 1); // Removing an item with index 'myIndex';

localStorage.setItem("myArray", JSON.stringify(myArray)); // Storing the changes
```

Comment: is there a way of looping through the whole Local storage? perhaps a for loop that runs till storage.length?

Comment: More on that... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745292/how-to-retrieve-all-localstorage-items-without-knowing-the-keys-in-advance

Comment: Good point, @Cat. Looping through localStorage might also be needlessly complicated; I've updated my original answer with a suggested alternative approach

Answer (score 1):

General approach:

```
function changeKeyforStorageItem(oldKey, newKey) {
   let myValue = localStorage.getItem(oldKey);
   localStorage.removeItem(oldKey);
   localStorage.setItem(newKey, myValue);
}
```

or :

```
 function changeKeyforStorageItem(oldKey, newKey) {
    localStorage.setItem(newKey, localStorage.getItem(oldKey));
    localStorage.removeItem(oldKey);
 }
```