# How can I access certain element's key in local storage?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sorting, local-storage

I have an array of objects like this and when I click the Remove Favorite button I want to delete the certain element from local storage. I'm deleting from the page with the removeLocal() function but it only deletes from the page, not from local storage. I want to delete it both. I'm generating random number when assigning local storage key. Is there way to access this key and delete the item?

[image]
[image]

**html:**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="profile" (ngModelChange)="detectChange($event)" (keyup)="findProfile()"
  placeholder="Enter the username..." class="input">
<div style="background-color: lightslategrey;">
  <ng-template [ngIf]="profile !== '' && user">
    <img [src]="user.avatar_url" alt="" class="userAvatar">
    <p>Username: {{user.login}}</p>
    <p>Location: {{user.location}}</p>
    <p>E-mail: {{user.email}}</p>
    <p>Blog Link: {{user.blog}}</p>
    <p>Member Since: {{user.created_at}}</p>
    <button [routerLink]="['', user.login.toLowerCase(), user.id ]" class="viewProfileButton" a>View
      Profile</button><br>
    <button (click)="localStorage()" class="viewProfileButton">Add to Favorite</button>
  </ng-template>
</div>

<div *ngIf="closeDiv">
  <div style="background-color: rgb(106, 106, 170);" *ngFor="let item of display">
    <p>Username: {{item.login}}</p>
    <p>Location: {{item.location}}</p>
    <p>ID: {{item.id}}</p>
    <button (click)="removeLocal(item.id)" class="viewProfileButton">Remove Favorite</button>
  </div>
</div>

<button (click)="consoleLog()" class="viewProfileButton">Console Log</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  user: any;
  profile: any;
  display: any;
  local: any;
  randomNumber: any;
  randomString: any;
  idString: any;
  keys: any;
  closeDiv: boolean = true;
  constructor(private userData: HttpService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.display = Object.values(localStorage).map((val: any) => JSON.parse(val));
    console.log('ngOnInit Works', this.display);
  }

  findProfile() {
    this.userData.updateProfile(this.profile);
    this.userData.getUser().subscribe((result) => {
      this.user = result;
    });
  }

  localStorage(id: any) {
    this.randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    this.randomString = this.randomNumber.toString();
    localStorage.setItem(this.randomString, JSON.stringify(this.user));
    this.display = Object.values(localStorage).map((val: any) => JSON.parse(val));
    console.log(this.display);
  }

  removeLocal(id: any) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.display.length; i++) {
      if (this.display[i].id === id) {
        this.display.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  detectChange(ev: any) {
    ev.length > 0 ? (this.closeDiv = false) : (this.closeDiv = true);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the call `localStorage.removeItem(key)` to your removeLocal function. Granted, you need to store your random keys somewhere, otherwise you will have to integrate [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745292/how-to-retrieve-all-localstorage-items-without-knowing-the-keys-in-advance/51647623) to parse through them.

```
  removeLocal(id: any, key: string) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.display.length; i++) {
      if (this.display[i].id === id) {
        this.display.splice(i, 1);
        localStorage.removeItem(key); // here
      }
    }
  }
```

**EDIT:** After a conversation in the comments, this solution can be simplified to remove a variable from the function header by storing a `storageKey` variable within display.

```
  removeLocal(id: any) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.display.length; i++) {
      if (this.display[i].id === id) {
        localStorage.removeItem(this.display[i].storageKey);
        this.display.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried it but key parameter is undefined. I guess I should send the parameter from html right?

Comment: yes, but before you pass in the parameter, you need to store it some where. something like `this.user.storageKey = this.randomString` before you set it in localStorage, so it would have to be in your `localStorage()` function. Otherwise you are abandoning them.

Comment: @DAktas I updated my solution with a a second option, just to simplify things a little more.