# How to get all item from local storage in blazor?

Tags: local-storage, blazor

I'm planning on create a get all item for local storage to pass in Indexed DB. I'm using Blazor WASM. This local storage code is from
[retrieve all localStorage items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745292/how-to-retrieve-all-localstorage-items-without-knowing-the-keys-in-advance) . I have this few error

> Invalid expression [, syntax error value expected

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'keys'

```
 private void allStorage()
{
   //error Invalid expression [
    var values = [],
        //error keys
        keys = Object.keys(localStore),
        i = keys.length;

    while (i--)
    {
        values.push(localStore.GetItem(keys[i]));
    }

    return values;
}
```

Comment: You can only access local storage using JsInterop. I would suggest using a library like: https://github.com/blazored/LocalStorage

Comment: @Kane yes I am using `Blazored Localstorage NuGet` my localtorage code in razor (C#) & it works but I just problem on how to call get all item

Answer (score 2):

To get all items you may want to *store all items as a single item* - a json object.
Once you have done that, you can get this single json object and extract all individual item values from it.