# localstorage key numbering breaks when removing an item

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, local-storage

Don't worry about how it got to be like this, but this is how my localstorage looks:

[image]

This is how it should look:

[image]

this is how my loop looks:

```
for(let i=0;i<localStorage.length;i++){
//I do something cool
}
```

Now imagine that the same numbering error is happening to say 15 values. How can I change either the key column in localstorage so that it starts at 0 and indents by 1 for every value, or my loop so that it runs from the first key to the last key.

Comment: Why do you even care if `i` matches or not? You have that `Key` there already.

Comment: How? -> Use an actual array (with `JSON.stringify()` / `JSON.parse()`)

Comment: @VLAZ If I doesnt match through the entire loop, the loop either doesn't run for all values, or returns NULL for a missing value.

Comment: @Andreas If I translate localstorage to an array, the key values will still be wrong, no?

Comment: @BalderKun but your screenshot shows you have something called `Key`. It shouldn't matter what `i` is if you just use the `Key` field. What am I missing?

Comment: [Using the Web Storage API - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

Comment: @VLAZ I will add another example

Comment: [How to retrieve all localStorage items without knowing the keys in advance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17745292)

Answer (score 0):

The `localStorage` works with key and values. You can loop through it like an javascript object.

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(localStorage)) {

}
```

Comment: Just a note, `for (const key in localStorage)` will catch all keys including `localStorage` methods and its length.

Comment: Yes @Alaa. I wrote it before testing...

Answer (score 0):

You can catch all keys in an array then use that array in your code.

```
    const lsKeys = Object.keys(localStorage);
    for(let i = 0; i < lsKeys.length; i++) console.log(localStorage[lsKeys[i]]);
```