# Angular local storage value being read before set

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage

Im working with an angular application which has a sidebar component. Depending on the role of the user signed in, there will be more options on the sidebar. For example, a superadmin will have an additional dashboard for him.

The issue is the role is being stored in local storage in the app component's ts while it is being retrived in the nav component ngAfterViewInit. But the code in ngAfterViewInit is being executed first such that it gets a null role.

Here is a code snippet:

App.component.ts

```
constructor
 (private auth: AuthService)

ngOnInit(){
 this.auth.
 authenticate.subscribe(res 
  =>{ this.storageService.
set('userRole', res.role) })
```

nav.component.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
   this.role = this.
   storageService.
   get('userRole')
```

storageservice.ts

```
get(key: string){
  const keyVal = string | null = 
  localStorage.getItem(key)

   if(stringValue){
      return JSON.parse(keyVal);
  }

}
```

The value returned is null. I logged it in console n saw that retrieving the value was executed before setting it.

Getting this error:

```
main.50d4493a21037afa5155.js:1 
    
   ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
at t._next (main.50d4493a21037afa5155.js:1:2189226)
at t.__tryOrUnsub (main.50d4493a21037afa5155.js:1:544147)
at t.next (main.50d4493a21037afa5155.js:1:543316)
at t._next (main.50d4493a21037afa5155.js:1:542366)
at t.next (main.50d4493a21037afa5155.js:1:542037)
at t._next (main.50d4493a21037afa5155.js:1:551777)
at t.next (main.50d4493a21037afa5155.js:1:542037)
at t._subscribe (main.50d4493a21037afa5155.js:1:1526055)
at e._trySubscribe (main.50d4493a21037afa5155.js:1:545724)
at t._trySubscribe (main.50d4493a21037afa5155.js:1:548182)
```

Im doing a check as posted for role in nav component then assign it to a variable

Comment: What is the `storageService` doing? Is it another layer above the built-in `localStorage`? If so, you can convert it to Observable approach and in components, you can _watch_ the changes to the local storage.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create a `BehaviorSubject` in the `StorageService` that the components/services can subscribe to and get the latest stored value.

Upon each `set` call, you can update the `BehaviorSubject` with the latest value, and all the subscribers will be called. You can use `map()` pipeable operator to filter by key.

And of course, you need to populate the subject on service startup:

```
export class StorageService{
  private currentStorage = new BehaviorSubject({});

 constructor() {
    this.updateSubject()
 }

  set(key: string, value: any){
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    this.updateSubject();
  }


  updateSubject(){
    this.currentStorage.next({...localStorage})
  }

  get(key: string){
    return localStorage.getItem(key)
  }

  watch(key: string){
    return this.currentStorage.pipe(
      map(items => items[key])
    )
  } 
}
```

In the `app.component`, you can set the value like before:

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.auth.authenticate.subscribe(res =>{ this.storageService.
set('userRole', res.role) }
   )
}
```

And in the `nav.component`, you can subscribe to it like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
   this.storageService.watch('userRole').subscribe(role => this.role = role)
}
```

You can find a working example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ffp2qi?file=src/app/storage.service.ts

Comment: actually I need to set the key in app component itself

Comment: What I posted is actually what you're asking. Please see the updated answer

Comment: getting an error for the map. Its expecting 2 args

Comment: Do you import `map` from `rxjs` like this `import { map } from 'rxjs';`?

Comment: i did this. But overall solution does not work.

Comment: Oops... I forgot to save the project. Can you please check the example project linked above?

Comment: man that spread in localStorage is neat!

Comment: @Jimmy Thank you! But all the credit for that goes to Alexey in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51647623/1331040) :)

Comment: @user20565161 Updated the answer. You need to populate the subject with the stored items upon the service creation.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz, getting an error in console. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') at t._next ()

Comment: Can you please post the full output of the error? And how are you trying to use the value `this.role` in the component?

Comment: It's not clear but are you trying to use it like `this.role[0]` or something? If so, note that the initial subscription callback may return `undefined`.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz, correct. How do I handle it ?

Comment: You can use [`optional chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to avoid getting an exception `this.role?.[0]`. Or you can use `if(this.role){ doSomething(this.role[0]) }`