# Clear localstorage values with certain prefix

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have stored several key value pairs which contains certain encrypted login information using  HTML5 localstorage variables. I have added a unique prefix to all key names say `TM_loginname` . Now I want to clear all the localstorage key-value pairs whose key starts with prefix TM_.
PS: I tried sessionstorage too, but it clears only when browser is closed.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Removing element while iterating is unsafe, so create an array to hold the keys that need to be removed. Then, iterate over that array to remove them:

```
var arr = []; // Array to hold the keys
// Iterate over localStorage and insert the keys that meet the condition into arr
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    if (localStorage.key(i).substring(0,3) == 'TM_') {
        arr.push(localStorage.key(i));
    }
}

// Iterate over arr and remove the items by key
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    localStorage.removeItem(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please always explain your code and don't simply throw code at us.

Comment: Can you reference why _"removing an element while iterating is unsafe"_?

Comment: Thank you for the comment dirkk, I'm new to this and I appreciate the guidance. Nit, I used two loops to avoid removing elements while, iterating which seems unsafe. Was this avoidable?

Comment: Let's say we have `var someArr = ['TM_a', 'TM_b' 'c'];`. When our loop index, i, is 0 we'll remove 'TM_a', which shifts the rest of the elements 'to the left'. Meaning, our loop index is 1, but 'TM_b' is currently in `someArr[0]`. After the iteration 'TM_a' is still in the array and we didn't achieve our goal. Now, there are ways to avoid this in JS, but seeing as our API to localStorage is with an interface, it seems prudent to use it instead of risking unpredictable results. If someone is more deeply familiar with the structure of localStorage, perhaps they have a better way?

Comment: **more:** `(localStorage.key(i).indexOf(path_key) >= 0)` also works, or use a variable to make it more scalable: `...substring(0, prefix.length) == prefix` 

Comment: Nit, you modify array which is iterated. You can get out of bounds bug.

People wrote that iterating backwards and removal is safe

Answer (score 21):

A more modern (ES2017) solution is as follows:

```
Object.entries(localStorage).map(
        x => x[0] # get keys
    ).filter(
        x => x.substring(0,3)=="TM_"
    ).map(
        x => localStorage.removeItem(x))
```

EDIT

Taken from the comments:

```
Object.keys(localStorage)
 .filter(x =>
    x.startsWith('TM_'))
 .forEach(x => 
    localStorage.removeItem(x))
```

Comment: The last operation in this pipeline might be better off being a `forEach` instead of a `map`. Map in this case yields nothing as `removeItem` returns `undefined`.

Comment: agreed, forEach is preferable since avoids unnecessary allocation. thx!

Comment: Would `x.startsWith` rather than `x.substring` be cleaner?

Comment: Since you need the keys, you can use Object.keys(localStorage) instead

`Object.keys(localStorage).filter(x => x.startsWith('TM_')).forEach(x => localStorage.removeItem(x))`

Answer (score 11):

*Using lodash. Enjoy.*

```js
_.forIn(window.localStorage, (value: string, objKey: string) => {
    if (true === _.startsWith(objKey, 'TM_')) {
        window.localStorage.removeItem(objKey);
    }
});
```

Comment: You can simplify the second line to: `if (_.startsWith(objKey, 'TM_')) {`

Answer (score 4):

save to localStorage using
`key = pref + version`

```
function remLSPref(pref, newName) {
    for (var key in localStorage) {
        if (key.indexOf(pref) == 0) {
            if (key != newName) {
                localStorage.removeItem(key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use like this:

```
var pref = 'myid_';
var key = pref + ver;

// rem old ls
remLSPref(pref, key);
```

Comment: this actually adrresses the issue and helps to remove dynamically created items with a certain prefix , +1 for that

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- keep an array of all the items you've created yourself or
- [loop over all localStorage items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8419509/1470607) and filter to get the ones you
  need.

Comment: Actually I am doing this(using loop) currently but I was looking for any better alternate than looping...

Comment: Even if there was a built-in method to do something akin to this, it would still use a loop. The only question here is how large of a loop you want to run over, on a complex site, localStorage may be quite large and it would be more reasonable to keep a list of the items yourself. On a small site, the performance difference isn't likely all that large if you don't want to track the items manually.

Comment: Thanks Nit, it seems I have to continue to store the keys and eventually clear them at logout

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the tip of [github](https://gist.github.com/n0m4dz/77f08d3de1b9115e905c):

```
findLocalItems(query) {
var i,
  results = [];
for (i in localStorage) {
  if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    if (i.match(query) || (!query && typeof i === 'string')) {
      var value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(i));
      results.push({ key: i, val: value });
    }
  }
}
return results;  }
```

And after, calling the function:

```
var keysFounded = findLocalItems(key);
if (keysFounded && keysFounded.length > 0) {
  keysFounded.forEach(k => {
    localStorage.removeItem(k.key);
  });
}
```