# How to get localStorage array data.

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am new  to localStorage. I set array in localstorage so how can get this value. My code as below.

```
$scope.lineItemID = data.id;
                    var itemtemp={
                        "itemid": data.id,
                        "qty": $scope.quantity
                    };
                    var itemqty=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("itemqty")) || [];
                    itemqty.push(itemtemp);
                    localStorage.setItem("itemqty", JSON.stringify(itemqty));
```

So my question is how can I get itemqty.qty as per itemid from localstorage

Comment: You can't `push()` on a normal JS object.

Comment: is this similar?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419354/get-html5-localstorage-keys

Comment: So how to add value in array for each item

Comment: You are doing it right.. itemQty is just an array after JSON.parse and you can extract ith elements like itemQty[i].qty

Answer (score 1):

try Below code

```
    $.each(data.itemqty, function(index, item) {
```

// append data using html //use item.name

```
});
```

OR try below

```
$.each(data, function(idx, item){
```

// append data using html 
//

});

Answer (score 0):

You are quite simply creating an array of objects `itemqty` and saving it in the browser's storage. When you do this:

```
var itemqty=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("itemqty")) || [];
//itemqty is available to you as an array of objects.
```

Suppose you are looking for the associated quantity for some `itemid` stored in the variable `foo`. You just need to traverse the parsed `itemqty` like so:

```
 $.each(itemqty, function( index, value ) {
  if(value.itemid == foo)
     {
       console.log(value.qty);
       // value.qty is the required quantity
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemqty'));

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if(items[i].itemid === itmId) {
            return items[i].qty;
        }                       
    }
```

I am using it & it's working