# How to keep the localStorage values in html after refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('insert'),
  s = 0;    //To increment the key(+1) each time the button is clicked and the user inputs the values so the first object's key is 1 then the second one is 2 and so on
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var ModelMake = prompt("Enter The Model Make"),
        ModelYear = prompt("Enter The Model Year"),
        Km = prompt("Enter The Amount Of Km"),
        Price = prompt("Enter The Price"),
        Status = prompt("Enter The Car's Status"),
        table = document.getElementById('table');
      var tableout = document.getElementById('tableout'),
        FinalPrice,
        Details;

      localStorage.setItem(s += 1, JSON.stringify({
        ModelMake: ModelMake,
        ModelYear: ModelYear,
        Km: Km,
        Price: Price,
        Status: Status,
        FinalPrice: FinalPrice,
        Details: Details
      }));
```

This code inserts the following variables values(user inputs them) in a row and each value is in a column (cell), when i refresh the object IS stored in the localStorage even when i close my browser obviously but i want a way to keep it in the html whether i refresh or close the browser without having to extract it from the localStorage because i don't know how and it's not really what i want.

Comment: I don't understand what you exactly want. You store it in the localStorage, but you don't want to do anything with it?

Comment: You can't. HTTP request do not remember their previous states, this is why you need some sort of browser or database storage. I recommend you keep using `localStorage`, as it's meant to keep data after refresh and close. As I see it it seems to be a *"I want to get a cookie without opening the cookie jar"*, type of question.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your data in a cookie. Here is a tutorial that may be of use: [Javascript and Cookies](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do exactly, what you are asking I see few options for you:

1. on page load you can go thru all localStorage keys, find max number and assign it to `S`(Here is answer how to go thru all keys: [Get HTML5 localStorage keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419354/get-html5-localstorage-keys)). I don't really like this way, but...
2. Store `s` value as separate key/value pair and extract it on page load