# Javascript: Retrieve all keys from sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, session, local-storage, session-storage

Is it not posssible to retrieve all keys/objects that I stored in sessionStorage (or localStorage)?

If I have done `sessionStorage.name = 'John'` and `sessionStorage.city = 'New York'`, isn't there a way to get a list that shows the keys `name` and `city`?

Comment: this may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419354/get-html5-localstorage-keys

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> to get a list that shows the keys **name** and **city**

Use `Object.keys()` function:

```
sessionStorage.name = 'John';
sessionStorage.city = 'New York';

console.log(Object.keys(sessionStorage));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Object.keys()` and `reduce()`:

```
var obj = Object.keys(localStorage).reduce(function(obj, key) {
   obj[key] = localStorage.getItem(key);
   return obj
}, {});

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 3):

With this you can assign all the data in local storage into an object:

```
let storage = {}
Object.keys(localStorage).forEach((key) => {
    storage[key] = localStorage.getItem(key);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to support IE9 or less (or are happy to use a Polyfills than you can use a combination of [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array. prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as follows:

```
Object.keys(localStorage).map(function(c,i,a){
  // do whatever
});
```

The `Object.keys()` returns an *array* of the enumerable values of the object passed to it with the added benefit of not enumerating through any properties in its prototype chain.

You can then run operations over this returned array with `Array.prototype.map()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the keys and their values as such.

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(sessionStorage)) {
    console.log({key, value});
};
```

this should work except IE11