# JavaScript local storage: Requesting all data?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to retrieve all data in local storage in one single call?

Without using specific key (getItem('key').

What I like is to load all data and then check them for a certain prefix.

Comment: `window.localStorage` ... ?

Comment: You can list all keys: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419354/get-html5-localstorage-keys

Comment: @Alexis Works. Awesome!!

Comment: @Thilo Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get certain items that staty with your custom prefix, you can first at all retrieve all `localStorage` keys, filter it, and then retrieve the data:

**ES5**

```
var prefix = 'your-prefix:'

var filteredStorage = Object.keys(localStorage)
  .filter(function(key) {
    return key.startsWith(prefix)
  })
  .map(function(key){
    return localStorage.getItem(key)
  })
```

**ES2015**

```
let prefix = 'your-prefix:'  
let filteredStorage = Object.keys(localStorage)
  .filter(key => key.startsWith(prefix))
  .map(key => localStorage.getItem(key))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(localStorage)
      .filter(key => localStorage[key].startsWith("e"))
      .map(key => localStorage[key]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all the keys

```
var local = localStorage;
for (var key in local) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

Also you can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

```
console.log(Object.keys(localStorage))
```