# How to add all local storage items in a loop?

Tags: javascript

```
import React from 'react'
import { Input, Form, Button } from 'antd';
import { LockTwoTone, MailTwoTone, EyeTwoTone, EyeInvisibleOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { login } from '@/services/Api.Login/index'
import { getProfile } from '@/services/Api.User';
 
const LoginForm = () => {

    const onFinish = async (values) => {
 
        const { email, role, userName, organisationId } = await getProfile(values);
        
        localStorage.setItem('email', email);     
        localStorage.setItem('role', role); 
        localStorage.setItem('userName', userName); 
        localStorage.setItem('organisationId', organisationId); 

        // var items = [ 'email', 'role', 'userName', 'organisationId' ]
        
    };

    return (null)
}

export default LoginForm
```

Comment: Can you go into more detail?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419354/get-html5-localstorage-keys)

Comment: store it in an array and loop through the array.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    const onFinish = async (values) => {
 
        const result = await getProfile(values);
        const items = [ 'email', 'role', 'userName', 'organisationId' ]
        items.forEach(key => {
          localStorage.setItem(key, result[key]);
        });
        
    };
```

Comment: This is a Good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
const { email, role, userName, organisationId } = await getProfile(values);
```

You can store it in an array

```
const arr = await getProfile(values);
```

Then use this what you have in the commentary as foundation for the loop

```
var items = [ 'email', 'role', 'userName', 'organisationId' ]
```

Loop through it

```
items.forEach(key => {
        localStorage.setIteam(key, arr[key]);
});
```