# Worklight Encrypted Offline Cache credentials mismatch with multiple apps installed?

Tags: encryption, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing two different hybrid apps in an IBM Worklight 6 project which make use of the Worklight Encrypted Offline Cache (EOC). That being said, everything seems to work fine with each of those apps individually. I can open the EOC, read, write, etc. However, if I try to run one app on the Blackberry10 simulator or the windows phone 8 simulator and then run the other afterward, the EOC gives me a "Credentials mismatch" error.

It seems like the EOC wants both of my apps to use the same credentials to access it.

Has anyone seen this issue or can anyone offer any advice?

*I should note that I do not see this issue when using EOC on iOS.* 
*(That being said, could this be a simulator issue?)*

Comment: EOC stores metadata and data in HTML5 Local Storage, if you [print the items stored there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5410874/186909) in both applications that may help you debug the issue. Maybe both applications are looking for the data in the same location? FYI: I've never used EOC on BlackBerry or Windows Phone.

Comment: Aren't the items encrypted though?

Comment: Yes, the data you store with EOC will be encrypted. I did not mean to give the impression it was not in comment above.

Comment: I'm not sure I'll be able to print one of the caches due to the "credentials mismatch" causing me to not be able to open it.

Comment: No need to open EOC to take advantage of my suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the culprit...

In the config.xml file for each app, there is a line about Widget Configuration:

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets"
version="1.0.0.0" id="[APP ID]" rim:backButton="exit">
```

Both of my apps had somehow ended up with the same APP ID which was causing them to try to access the same encrypted cache.