# How to get all the keys in a native script local-storage

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have created an angular native script project and i am using the "nativescript-localstorage". I want to get all the keys in the storage ,how will i do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I show all the localStorage saved variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410820/how-can-i-show-all-the-localstorage-saved-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through all the `localStorage` items and use the `localStorage.key(index)` to get the key and use it in `localStorage.getItem` to get the value.

```
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    let key = localStorage.key(i);
    let val = localStorage.getItem(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage`

### Creating Entries

```
let key = 'Item 1';
localStorage.setItem(key, 'Value');
```

### Reading Entries

```
let myItem = localStorage.getItem(key);
```

### Updating Entries

```
localStorage.setItem(key, 'New Value');
```

### Deleting Entries

```
localStorage.removeItem(key);
```

### Clearing Everything

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use localstorage.[length](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-localstorage#localstoragelength----number-of-items-stored) that will return you the number of keys stored.

```
console.log("Keys stored", localStorage.length);
```

You can also iterate for all the keys stored in localstorage
[localstorage.key](http://for%20(let%20i%20=%200;%20i%20%3C%20localStorage.length;%20i++)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20let%20key%20=%20localStorage.key(i);%20%20%20%20%20let%20val%20=%20localStorage.getItem(key);%20%7D) return the key name at this position

```
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    let key = localStorage.key(i); // Will return the name of the key
    let val = localStorage.getItem(key); // will return the value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**get length of local storage keys.**
returns number of keys stored

> localStorage.length

Return the key name at this position

> localStorage.key(id)

```
let n = localStorage.length;
    for(let i=0;i<n;i++){
        console.log("--->",localStorage.key(i));
    }
```