# Local Storage's Synchronicity

Tags: javascript, json, session, local-storage

If all websites access different localstorage where can i see localstorage of all websites at one place like it would be atleast in some folder in my computer ? And yes, i know we can go to application tab in developer's tool but it just shows localstorage of that website and i just got to know about this strange fact that different website will have different localStorage on my browser ,can someone explain that too ,why is it so ?

Even any ideas regarding this ,are more then welcomed in comments ! Thnx in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show all the localStorage saved variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410820/how-can-i-show-all-the-localstorage-saved-variables)

Comment: You mean, where on your computer is your Local Storage data stored?

Comment: Yes where on my device is all localstorage's data stored ?

Comment: Oh yes it did,but also like why individual website's are getting individual localstorage ,what's the idea behind that and for what localstorage is used today

Comment: Like the name suggests; local storage is stored locally on the device of the browser. With this you can *save* values, close the browser, open the browser again, and load the values back in. Like a *save-state* or save in a game. Local storage is only available on the sites that have values stored on your machine and can't be interchanged between websites for security reasons. A scenario for this might be that someone stored your password on one site (don't ever do this), and the next site you visit tries to read that value without you knowing, now having your password.

Comment: right sir @EmielZuurbier Clear now ! thnx --tonn